# How can I type smart to allow only keys of class properties as method argument in typescript

Tags: typescript

How can I add a type to the arguments of setProperty method 'key' and 'value'
Is there any more of dynamic way rather than `string` or just adding all the possible types like `'name' | 'age' | 'sex'` so it is more scalable.

```js
class Person {
   name: string;
   age: number;
   sex: 'men' | 'women'

   setProperty(key: string, value: any): Person {
      this[key] = value
      return this
   }
}
```

Comment: The only thing I could think of was using `keyof Person` but the problem is that this includes `"setProperty"` which you probably don't want. You could do `Omit<keyof Person, "setProperty">` but it's quite messy.

Comment: In any case I suppose you don't want to allow all properties to be set using `setProperty` so it's best to just list them out explicitly like `"name" | "age" | "sex"` anyways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can determine the available values for `key` and even the type of `value` *for that property name* by using a `keyof` type:

```js
class Person {
   name?: string;
   age?: number;
   sex?: 'men' | 'women'

   setProperty<K extends keyof Person>(this: Person, key: K, value: Person[K]): Person {
      this[key] = value
      return this
   }
}

const p = new Person();
p.setProperty('name', 'John Smith');  // fine
p.setProperty('age', 40);  // fine
p.setProperty('sex', 'foo');  // not fine
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gKGntYAtvAPwBc0EALogJZoDmA3LnmA6RWgK6EBGSFnkrwAHuWgByYmknQAPlIDuKGZOysRVWIhQAHJFQCeAHgDS0MVXhoAJjADW8IygBmcJKjQA+ABRUAC1oICgRkdAAaaCcjCjMogDcwEG54UM90AG0zAF0ASnTwjBxhYUDgzJic6ABeaCSU+E1hRHgqbkQMcohNAF9sfuxgdGpoPVroNHglDyLfPJY9ADoINp19QyNfSQJiSSjJACkUAIwAZUJaQMkF7GXV7V0DRGNt9nh96AAWAAZb+7WT0221Wok+klcKBQNxYQA)

If you don't want `setProperty` to be reassignable, which seems likely, you could use `keyof Omit<Person, 'setProperty'>` instead.

Comment: This is not safe because you can overwrite `setProperty` as well using something like `p.setProperty('setProperty', () => p)`.

Comment: @cdimitroulas yep I'd actually just edited to cover that! Of course you can still do that outside `setProperty`...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you so much!! that's exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: @OtaniShuzo no problem, but see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.